# C: Manipulate a structure declaired in the main from a created thread without the use of global variables

Tags: c, linux, variables, pthreads, structure

I'm trying to understand the use of threads in an application (I'm aware what I'm doing may be stupid in some sense) and I'm trying to understand how to manipulate variables declared in a structure in main from a created thread. So far i have:

```
typedef struct Chi_Server {

    int thread_status;
    int active_connections;

    pthread_t thread_id;
    pthread_attr_t thread_attribute;
    struct thread_info *tinfo;

} CHI_SERVER;
```

---

```
int main(void) {

    CHI_SERVER *chi_server;

    chi_server_start_server(chi_server);

    if (pthread_create(&chi_server->thread_id, (void *) &chi_server->thread_attribute, &chi_server_runtime, &chi_server)) {

        perror("Creating main thread");

    }

    initscr();
    noecho();
    cbreak();
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    curs_set(0);

    do {

        chi_server_time_alive(chi_server);
        chi_server_display(chi_server);

    } while (getch() != 113);

    nocbreak();
    endwin();

    chi_server_stop_server(chi_server);

    return 0;

}
```

---

```
void *chi_server_runtime(void *chi_server) {

    chi_server->server_stats.active_connections = 1;

}
```

I just made the = 1 so I could see if the structure variables could be manipulated in the main. So far I am completely stumped. Does anyone have an idea how to manipulate the structure declared in main?

Comment: In your call to pthread_create(), it should be `server` not `&server`. You're passing a pointer to a pointer to SERVER.

Comment: @DaV `passing a pointer to a pointer to SERVER` Why? notice `SERVER *server = arg;`

Comment: i realized the error in that. I have changed it to reflect

Comment: How do you declare `server` in main() If you declared like `SERVER *server` Then Dav is correct

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan In `main()`, if `server` isn't a pointer, the code won't compile. Calling `pthread_create()` passing `&server` has type `SERVER**`. James C, can you post how you declare the structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused about references when calling pthread_create; your last argument "&server" probably should just be server.
You cannot dereference a pointer to void as you are doing in server_runtime.
You should assign a struct Server pointer to the void pointer and use that.

Try this compiling with `gcc -Wall thread.c -o thread -lpthread`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct Server {
    pthread_attr_t thread_attribute;
    pthread_t thread_id;
    int active_connections;
};

void * server_runtime(void *);

/* Error checking omitted for clarity. */
int main()
{
    struct Server *server;
    void *result;

    server = malloc(sizeof(struct Server));
    pthread_attr_init(&server->thread_attribute);
    pthread_create(&server->thread_id, &server->thread_attribute, server_runtime, server);
    pthread_attr_destroy(&server->thread_attribute);
    pthread_join(server->thread_id, &result);
    printf("%d\n", server->active_connections);
    free(server);

    return 0;
}

void * server_runtime(void *p)
{
    struct Server *server = p;
    server->active_connections = 1;
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Strangely enough it was the fact that I had not allocated memory for the structure that was causing the issue. I appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 1):

In void *server_runtime(void *server).
You have to tell what kind of type *server is.

I havent seen your declaration of server, but i suppose it looks something like this

```
    int main()
    {
     struct yourstruct server;

      if (pthread_create(&server->thread_id, (void *) &server->thread_attribute, 
              &server_runtime, &server)) 
      {
          perror("Creating main thread");
      }

    }

    void *server_runtime(void *_server) 
    {
        struct yourstruct *server = _server;
        server->active_connections = 1;
    }
```

Probably missed something as usual.
Good luck.